# Are there further primes of the form $\varphi(n)^{\varphi(\varphi(n))}+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

For positive integers $n$ , define $$f(n):=\varphi(n)^{\varphi(\varphi(n))}+1$$ where $\varphi(n)$ denotes the totient function.

According to my calculation, for the following positive integers $n$ , $f(n)$ is a prime number : $$[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 18, 97, 119, 153, 194, 195, 208, 224, 23
8, 260, 280, 288, 306, 312, 336, 360, 390, 420]$$ and upto $n=10^4$, no further prime occurs. For $n>6$ , we have $\varphi(\varphi(n))>1$ and $\varphi(n)>1$ hence $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ must be a power of $2$. The number is then a generalized Fermat-number.

> Do further primes $f(n)$ exist ?

Comment: I wanted to search for such primes with PFGW, but I did not find a command. Does PFGW support the totient-function ? factordb apparently does not supprt the totient-function.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that $\phi(\phi(n))$ is a power of $2$ for $n>6$.  For example $\phi(\phi(19))=\phi(18)=6$.

Comment: @paw88789 To get a prime , this must be the case.

Comment: @paw88789 I think that the assertion is that *to get a prime result,* $\phi(\phi(n))$ must be a power of $2$ - but a justification for that would be nice.

Comment: @Joffan if $q$ is an odd prime factor of $n$ , then $a^n+1$ is divisible by $a^{n/q}+1$

Comment: @Peter; Ok, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked it up in the OEIS? I just did. No relevant results.

Comment: Then I tried `Select[Range[1000], PrimeQ[EulerPhi[#]^EulerPhi[EulerPhi[#]] + 1] &]` in Wolfram Alpha. I probably need Mathematica if I want to confirm your assertion up to $10^4$.

Comment: @RobertSoupe : Pari/GP is a free software which is able to deal with that problem nicely. Note btw, that many $n$ have the same value $\varphi(n)$ and thus the same $\text{isprime}(f(n)$ -result, so time consumption could be much reduced when you avoid multiple computation of the $f(n)$ at different $n$ leading to the same result.

Comment: If we look only at different $\varphi(n)$ I get the only primes for $[\varphi,\varphi(\varphi)]$ as  $[1, 1],[2, 1],[4, 2],[6, 2],[96, 32]$ (here I used the strong pseudoprime-test in Pari/GP). It needed 700 sec for the whole table $n$ up to $10^4$ Up to $n=10^4$ we need only do $66$ actual primetests, if we exclude all cases where $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ is not a perfect power of $2$ as indicated by Peter in a comment above.

Comment: According to my calculation , $n$ must exceed $33\ 000$ and the exponent must be at least $2\ 048$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly just a summary of what I have found that is to big for a comment.

Since $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ must be a power of $2$, $\varphi(n)=2^m p_1 p_2 p_3...p_m$. Where each of the $p_i$ is a distinct Fermat prime. Thus we have
$$\varphi(n)^{\varphi(\varphi(n))}+1=(2^mp_1p_2p_3...p_m)^{2^r}+1.\tag{1}$$
We also have that
$$n=2^uq_1q_2...q_sp_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_m^{e_m}$$
where the $q_i$ are primes of the form $2^dp_i+1$, and the $e_i$ are each $0,1$ or $2$. If a $q_i$ is present in the factorization, then $e_i$ is at most $1$.

If we want to answer your question, it will probably be easiest to work with the right side of $(1)$.